# wpf netframeworkcore 3.1 mvvm Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-core

I try to hide an object via the properties of another object
I do not know what the problem is, but it does not work
  Binding code

I tried to follow the implementation to make sure the value of the property did not change and I found that it changed, but there is no effect on the object

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Grid Margin="25,0,0,0"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock  Text="اسم المستخدم" 
                                    FontWeight="Light"
                                    FontSize="18"
                                    Foreground="White"
                                    Background="Transparent"
                                    Width="230"
                                    Opacity="0.5"
                                    Height="28"
                                    Visibility="{Binding Path=VisbTbU , Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <TextBox FontFamily="Helvetica"
                                 FontWeight="Light"
                                 FontSize="18"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                 Foreground="White"
                                 Background="Transparent"
                                 BorderThickness="0"
                                 Width="235"
                                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                 Opacity="0.5"
                                 Height="25"
                                 Text="{Binding UserLog}"
                        />

                    </Grid>
                    <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="Account"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                Foreground="White"/>
                </StackPanel>
```

viewmodel code

```
 public VmWinLogin()
            {

                VisbTbp = Visibility.Visible;
                VisbTbp = Visibility.Visible;
                UserLog = "";
                UserPass = "";

            }

private Visibility _VisbTbU ;

public Visibility VisbTbU
{
    get => _VisbTbU;
    set
    {
        _VisbTbU = value;
       // OnPropertyChanging();
       OnPropertyChanging();
    }

}


private string _UserLog ;
    public string UserLog
    {
        get => _UserLog .Trim();
        set
        {
            _UserLog = value .Trim();
            OnPropertyChanging();
            if (_UserLog == "")
            {
                VisbTbU = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                VisbTbU = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }

    }
```

basemodel code

```
public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanging([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanging?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

Comment: Invoking the PropertyChanging event has no effect here. You should invoke PropertyChanged instead.

Comment: invoke PropertyChanged It also did not work

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
         
        }